# jQuery Slider having three items at a time

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel, jcarousel

I am trying to create a jQuery Slider either by using  jCarousel or something else like this one http://goo.gl/4puAeM

Slider will have two groups, each group will have three items and having different trasnion time for each.

Say one group arrives and initialy only one item within the group will be visible after x seconds second item will appear and same for the third item.

Thanks in Advance,

Regards

Comment: So what's the question? You don't expect us to write your code do you?

Comment: Hi Shivam, I am doing to in on localhost but have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Hi Mike, I just need a basic idea if you can help that would be greatful.

Answer (score 0):

your website is giving below error

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.intigris.nl/templates/template-home/css/joomla.css
```

Please check joomla.css file path is correct

Comment: Hi,
this is not my website, I am trying to create a jQuery slider like the one on the home page (the three boxes).

Comment: try writing your code in http://jsfiddle.net/  and if you get any problem then ask.

Comment: Anil I am actually confused how to do it, if you can suggest some basic idea that would be grateful

Comment: I Know how to create slider using  jCarousel  but dont know how to give the effect that the boxes have when the slide change. If you can see the effect on the HomePage boxes.